# Why would one not be hired because one's expected pay range was low?

Tags: salary, hiring-process

Less than forty-eight hours after an interview<sup>†</sup>, I  received an email confirming that I was no longer being considered for a position, but strangely the reason given for rejection was "your desired rate of compensation does not correspond with the hourly pay range available for this position." On the online application, I chose the lowest available option ($5.85 - $8.00) and in the first part of the interview I was told that the position had a starting pay over $9 per hour (I think it was $9.30). Furthermore, on the application I indicated "Yes, I would be open to discussing a starting rate other than what I indicated."

The previous active rejections had much vaguer language (e.g., "we are unable to move forward with your application at this time", "we are unable to consider your application at this time").

An accidental selection of the wrong rejection reason from a list or the intentional selection of an inaccurate but least offensive option might explain such, but it just seemed odd. (A less credible theory would be that "out-of-range pay expectation" presents less of a red flag to casual review, e.g., in avoiding age discrimination concerns.)

The rejection reason might be accurate if an expectation of lower pay assumes an expectation of lower effort and responsibility, but it would be sad if lower self valuation or a willingness to trade pay for opportunity are significant negative factors.

I do not expect an authoritative answer (unless a telepath provides an answer ☺), but I am curious both why this response might be given (rather than a generic "not interested at this time").

---

<sup>†</sup> I made several mistakes in the interview and was not a strong candidate for the position, so the rejection itself was not surprising.

Comment: I would follow up with the interviewer to clarify

Comment: One reason interviewers ask you salary requirements is an easy screen to find people that are under-qualified for a position (not saying it is a good filter just that it happens).

Answer (score 4):

It *is entirely possible* that by quoting a very low amount you painted yourself as unmotivated, or as having very low confidence in your own skills.

We have several questions on this site about how to handle salary negotiations, and the key piece of advice that keeps coming up is that you shouldn't talk numbers, and it might be worth reading them.

That being said, I think that may not have been the real reason you were rejected. To me their reply sounds like a polite rejections more so than anything else.

If you want to get more information, or a sense of whether they are lying or not, you can try calling them trying to talk to someone, but most likely they will not elaborate.

Comment: Incidentally, "shouldn't talk numbers" did not apply in this case because the online application form required selecting a desired hourly pay range (the position was "Retail Support Signing Team Associate" which does not strike me as the type of position where pay negotiation is usual). I do have low confidence in my skills. Since the response had the signs of a form letter, a polite but accurate rejection might not have been an option. I agree that "likely they will not elaborate", so I am not strongly motivated to waste their time, but I hoped there might be some rationale obvious to others.

Answer (score 3):

I had to restart my career after a stroke and I learned this the hard way.

Asking for too little throws up several red flags to an employer.

1. You haven't done your research.  Employers know what a job typically pays, if you ask for too little, it could say that you have no real understanding of the job, it's duties or what it's worth.  BIG red flag
2. There is something wrong with you.  If you're asking for less than the job is worth, an employer might figure that you have a bad employment record, disabilities, or other drama/difficulties that have kept you from being employed.
3. You're desperate.  An employer might take it as you wanting a job, any job, it doesn't matter so long as it's a paycheck.  The natural question to an employer after that is "what happens when he's no longer desperate?"  Red flag for a flight risk here.  Turnover is a nasty hobgoblin for employers.  It costs a good deal of money to hire someone and bring them up to speed.  They are not going to invest the money if they think you are going to leave.

The solution is to go and research the salary ranges for the job you are applying for pay in your area.  Salariy.com and other sites could help you there.  Be prepared and know what the job pays.  Don't make the same mistake twice.

Comment: I think this answer is reading into the salary range too deeply. The salary range was created to see if a applicant fits within their budget requirements. Ex. If the position was approved for 9/hr then it wouldn't make sense to hire someone asking outside of that range. Some HR requires that applicants get exactly that amount or else.

Comment: No, I'm perfect, as always.  The OP wanted to know why, and those are all reasons I've seen and had explained to me as I got back into the workforce.